# android source not matching jar, in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Android 4.0.3 (API 15).  When I stop in the debugger and step into the source for Android, the source isn't matching - that is, I end up some arbitrary number of lines outside of the function I stepped into.  It appears that the SDK manager is downloading a version of source slightly different than the jar.

- I tried uninstalling the jar (through the Android SDK Manager) and reinstalling.  Same problem.
- The Manifest points to version 15.
- The java Build Path (project - properties) shows version 15.
- when I hover over the tab for the particular android source file, it shows the correct path.

What am I missing?

One more comment: in the Java Build Path, it automatically adds an entry called "Android 4.0.3" even though I already added "android.jar".  Regardless, the source paths are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is obvious in retrospect :)  The source you use to debug has to match the version on your device, not the minimum version.  The trick was getting Eclipse to "let go" of its source setting so I could point it to the correct version.